# Adding additional string to {x:Bind} in XAML Universal Windows Platform

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am new to XAML. I would like to add additional string to x:bind

I have tried

```
<AppBarToggleButton Icon="Phone" Label="E-Mail To {x:Bind  e_mail}" />
<AppBarToggleButton Icon="Phone" Label="{"E-Mail To" + x:Bind  e_mail}" />
```

I would like to get "E-Mail to email@email.com"

But no success. Thanks for help.

Comment: Use a Binding Converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a converter for this:

```
public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        return string.Format(parameter.ToString(), value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add this to yor page/control/app resources:

```
<converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
```

And then use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind e_mail}" 
    Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}" 
    ConverterParameter="E-Mail To {0}!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own `StringFormatConverter` you can use the [builtin converter from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.converters.stringformatconverter?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0):

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:converter="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <converter:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

There are also some other useful builtin converters, check them out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.converters?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0